# Integer Optimization for a rational function

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

Let $f(m,n)=\frac{1+(2^{n-1}-1)(2^{m-1}-1)}{2^{mn}}$ where $m,n \in  \mathbb{Z}^+ - \{0\}$. Suppose $mn=10000$. How should we choose $m$ and $n$ so that $f(m,n)$ is minimized.

Comment: Hmm. $f(m,n)$ is symmetric with relation to $m$ and $n$, so probably if $m \approx n$, you'll get pretty interesting results ... Also it's worth checking the boundaries.

Comment: Hint: There are two possibilities for $(n, m)$ for which the product in the numerator is negative. In all other cases, the product is positive.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know, that $mn=10\,000=10^4$, then your function is $f(m,n)=1+10^{-4}(2^{m-1}-1)(2^{n-1}-1)$.  Since $10^{-4}>0$, it suffices to minimize $(2^{m-1}-1)(2^{n-1}-1)$. For $m=10^4/n$, we get $$g(n)=(2^{10^4/n-1}-1)(2^{n-1}-1).$$ Since both factors are positive for $1<n<10^4$, we get the minimal value 0 at $n\in \{1,10^4\}$. Equivalently, the minimum of $f$ is attained at $(m,n)=(1,10^4)$ or $(m,n)=(10^4,1)$.